# NSFetchRequest data into a view?

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am just getting started with the CoreData API and am following a few tutorials. I get the basics of storing and retrieving objects, but am having trouble connecting all the pieces in terms of MVC.

I have a CustomView into which I draw some stuff with CoreAnimation, including some text layers that will get their strings from an NSManagedObject. I started with a basic CoreData application template so the managedObjectContext etc are declared in the appDelegate, and I'm just not sure how I should be getting data from the CoreData stack into the view. By the way, this is all in code, not interface builder.

So my question is, if I want to build my app in a pure MVC way, how should I go about getting data from the stack into the view? How should I give my view access to the initialized NSManagedObjectContext, for example?

I have been reading Cocoa Design Patterns but am a bit of a dunce when it comes to MVC. I know its a pretty general question, but if someone can just say, "set the delegate, grab a pointer..." whatever it is, that would be great!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did some more poking around and it seems the easiest way to do this is to get a pointer to the AppDelegate and then a pointer to the managedObjectContext. From there, execute a fetch request and put it into your view!

Answer (score 0):

In a good tutorial [Björn Sållarp](http://blog.sallarp.com/iphone-core-data-uitableview-drill-down/) does it this way:

From the app delegate he creates the rootViewController and sends it the context with:

```
RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

rootViewController.managedObjectContext = context;
rootViewController.entityName = @"Counties";
```

In the rootViewController's h file you declare:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

Create its property:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

and in m you

```
@synthesize managedObjectContext;
```

Then its there for your use.